# Page refresh on button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I am calling a javascript function via a button click to hide and show content.But when i click the button the whole page is refreshed.

Here is my code:
lcont.ascx

```
<asp:Button ID="lbutt" runat="server" Text="test" OnClientClick="Javascript: show(1); " />
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        $("#cont1").hide();
        $("#cont2").show();
    }
 }
```

Next i have the following code in cont.aspx

```
    <div id="cont1" >    
        helo world
    </div>

    <div id="cont2"   style="  display:none; " >
            heloo nepal
        </div>
```

- lcont.ascx is a user control file that is called to the cont.aspx page via masterpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

**Option 1**

Simply add `return false;` to your existing code to prevent postback:

```
OnClientClick="Javascript: show(1); return false;"
```

**Option 2**

Add it to your function:

```
OnClientClick="return show(1);"

function show(id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        $("#cont1").hide();
        $("#cont2").show();
    }

    return false;
 }
```

**Option 3**

Replace your ASP.Net button with a plain old HTML button.

```
<button id="lbutt" type="button" onClick="show(1)">Test</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add **return false** to function.

```
<asp:Button ID="lbutt" runat="server" Text="test" OnClientClick="return show(1); " />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(id) {
        if (id == 1) {
            $("#cont1").hide();
            $("#cont2").show();
        }
        return false;
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: @freefaller it's ok as I think.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ, fair point, I withdraw my comment.  But the code is identical to an answer already provided, with less explanation, so my -1 remains